# Serverless cloudformation: cast environment variable to number

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless, serverless-framework

I am using [serverless step functions plugin](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-step-functions), I need to specify the timeout from an environment variable. The problem is I don't know how to cast it to a number (expected by Cloudformation at runtime), I didn't find any helper function to do this:

`serverless.yml`

```yaml
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    MyStateMachine:
      name: 'MyStateMachine'
      definition:
        Comment: ''
        StartAt: Worker
        States:
          Worker:
            Type: Task
            Resource: arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.waitForTaskToken
            InputPath: $
            ResultPath: $
            OutputPath: $
            TimeoutSeconds: ${env:TIMEOUT_SECONDS} # Need this to be casted to a number
            Parameters:
              # ...              
            Catch:
              - ErrorEquals: ["States.ALL"]
                Next: Failure
            Next: Success

          Failure:
            Type: Fail

          Success:
            Type: Succeed
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Cloudformation` you can declare a parameter at the top of the `Cloudformation` File

Make the parameter value default to the environment variable

```yaml
     Parameters:
          TimeoutSecs:
            Description: The specified timeout from an environment
            Type: Number
            Timeout: "60"
            Default: ${{ env:TIMEOUT_SECONDS} }
```

According to the Docs Define the `Type` as a number
From the [AWS `Cloudformation` Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html)

`Number`
An integer or float. AWS `CloudFormation` validates the parameter value as a number; however, when you use the parameter elsewhere in your template (for example, by using the Ref intrinsic function), the parameter value becomes a string.

For example, users could specify "8888".

List
An array of integers or floats that are separated by commas. AWS CloudFormation validates the parameter value as numbers; however, when you use the parameter elsewhere in your template (for example, by using the Ref intrinsic function), the parameter value becomes a list of strings.

For example, users could specify `"80,20"`, and a Ref would result in `["80","20"]`.